# SQL Server - Is it a good idea to persist temporary stats built on AG read-only secondary?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I am curious if there are any benefits to running the below query every hour or even once a day to track whenever a temporary stat is created on an AG secondary/read-only replica and then having a process to create that same stat on the primary database so it gets replicated across and is also persisted. The main advantage being that if a server restarts, SQL will already have the stats it previously requested or if a failover occurs then those stats will already be there as well. I am wondering if this is overkill and also if it actually achieves anything since SQL Server is pretty solid at generating/updating stats automatically if enabled.

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID, name, auto_created,
user_created, is_temporary
FROM sys.stats
WHERE is_temporary = 1;
```

Comment: What advantage would one gain from putting stats on the Primary Replica in the event that the Primary subsequently fails over over?

Comment: User selects from read only secondary and temp stat is created... that came (which points to a separate AG on the same server) fails over to a different server and now that temp stat does not exist. Had it been persisted, it would exist on all secondary replicas. Another example that is much simpler would be a server restart.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the topology you're referring to, but in the case of a two-replica toplogy, when the Primary fails over it's just going to cut over to the Secondary that you just pulled the statistics from anyway. In a toplogy with multiple Secondary replicas, then the one that becomes the new Primary will likely be used in the same way that the previous Primary was being used (writes, etc), and therefore had no need for those statistics (if they didn't naturally already exist on the previous Primary anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think it's up to you to determine if something like this provide any benefit.

#### Do queries suck bad on secondary because of missing statistics?

Probably not, they suck because they're written by the BI team

#### How much does it take to build statistics?

If those are auto generated statistics it's going to be quick compared to the execution of the query, so you're going to have statistics anyway

#### Do you have auto update statistics async enabled?

If so, you should probably turn this setting back to its default, so every execution of the query is going to benefit of updated statistics!

#### In conclusion...

...I think you're over thinking the whole process, but test all these things and evaluate yourself!